# Normal map artifacts in cycles but not eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, normal-map

I cant seem to figure this out in eevee my normal map looks like it should but in cycles there are tons of artifacts and it looks terrible. The normal maps are in non-color space and the normal type is Open-GL.[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be shadow terminator artifacts.

Comment: I just found out about that do you think that is causing the strange shading on the object too.